# Unable to modify date stored in a file

Tags: c#, datetime, file-io, formatting

```
class Planner
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Date To Be Edited Is");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The Edited Date Is:");
        string Date = Console.ReadLine();
        StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();
        string temp = "";
        string[] file = File.ReadAllLines("Dates.txt");
        foreach (string line in file)
        {
                if (line.Contains(Date))
                {
                        DateTime Test;
                        if(DateTime.TryParseExact(Date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out Test) == true)
                        temp = line.Replace(input, Date);
                        newFile.Append(temp + "\r\n");
                        continue;
                }
                newFile.Append(line + "\r\n");
            }
            File.WriteAllText("Dates.txt", newFile.ToString());
    } 
}
```

I am trying to make a code that would let the users modify a date stored in the text file only in the specified format. This code doesn't seem to work. What went wrong and how can i make it work?

The Following information is stored in my text file

```
          10/13/2013
          10/18/2013
          05/08/2013
```

I want to modify this date 10/18/2013 to 11/18/2014
The user can only enter date in the specified format MM/dd/yyyy
Any other format must be rejected.
The modifying date part of my code works but accepting only the specified date format doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What is the output your are receiving vs what you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the date you want to look for is stored in `input`, and the date you want to replace it with is `Date`?

But you have:

```
if (line.Contains(Date))
```

I think you want to change that to

```
if (line.Contains(input))
```

And I have no idea why that `DateTime.TryParseExact` call is there. It doesn't seem to be doing you any good. If you want to verify that what the user input was a good date, do it when the user inputs it, and tell the user if it's invalid. There's no reason to check the user's input at every iteration of the loop.

Also, rather than calling `newFile.Append(line + "\r\n")`, call `newFile.AppendLine(line)`.

Comment: Every time, you come to my friends and my rescue@ Jim Mischel

Comment: @MatildaBeckham: Happy to help out. If this solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer. (Click the check mark.)